# SQL Date Range only show data for the last hour

Tags: sql-server, range

I want to do a mssql date range to return the data for an hour time range. Meaning, I want to return the data for the last hour, but not for the last hour from the current time.

```
Declare @today datetime
set @today=GETDATE()
select *  from table1  where
datetime>= DATEADD(hh,-2,@Today)
```

For example, the current time is 11:50:00 a.m.  I would like the query to return all the data between 10:00:00 a.m. to 10:59:00 a.m.  My variables cannot be static. I would like it dynamic, so no matter what time of the day I run the query it only return the last hour data no matter what time is it now. So it could be any time between 11:00:00 a.m. until 11:59:00 a.m., I still want the result to return data from 10 a.m until 10:59 a.m.

Thank you

Comment: Please don't use shorthand like `hh` - [it will bite you someday, I promise](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx). If you mean `HOUR`, spell out `HOUR`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a slightly simpler way:

```
DECLARE @d SMALLDATETIME;

SELECT @d = DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, '20000101', GETDATE()) - 1, '20000101');

SELECT @d;
```

Now you can use `@d` in your query, e.g.

```
WHERE col >= @d AND col < DATEADD(HOUR, 1, @d);
```

This is an open-ended date range. Please don't think about the "end" of the range or consider this a `BETWEEN` query. `BETWEEN 10:00 AND 10:59` is not a very wise approach, because you may miss data from `10:59:00.003 -> 10:59:59.997`. [Background info on why `BETWEEN` is evil](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
declare @lowerRange datetime = 
dateadd(hh,datepart(hour,dateadd(hh,-1,getdate())) , 
        cast(cast(getdate() as date) as smalldatetime) )

declare @upperRange datetime = dateadd(hour,1,@lowerRange)


select * from yourtable where yourdate between @lowerRange and @upperRange
```

Comment: This works out to "BETWEEN 10:00 AND 11:00" which isn't correct - you will include data from 11:00 even that shouldn't be included.

Answer (score 1):

This returns an hour range, of the previous hour to now; meaning that if it was `11:35AM`, it would return `10 AM to 11 AM`:

```
DECLARE @today DATETIME, @hour DATETIME, @hourtwo DATETIME
SET @today = GETDATE()
-- Test other times
--SET @today = '2013-11-04 11:37.22'
SELECT @hour = DATEADD(hh,-2,@today)
SELECT @hourtwo = DATEADD(hh,-1,@today)

SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,ROUND(CAST(@hour as float) * (24/1),0)/(24/1)) AS PreviousHourBegin

SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,ROUND(CAST(@hourtwo as float) * (24/1),0)/(24/1)) AS PreviousHourEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
DECLARE @D DATETIME
SET @D = GETDATE()
SELECT @D AS 'Date',
DATEADD(HOUR,-1,DATEADD(MINUTE,-(DATEPART(MINUTE, @D)),DATEADD(SECOND,-(DATEPART(SECOND, @D)),DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @D)),@D)))) AS 'Range start',
DATEADD(MINUTE,-(DATEPART(MINUTE, @D)),DATEADD(SECOND,-(DATEPART(SECOND, @D)),DATEADD(MILLISECOND,-(DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @D)),@D))) AS 'Range end'
```

For the date:

```
2013-11-04 17:35:51.843
```

This will return a range like:

```
Start: 2013-11-04 16:00:00.000  
End: 2013-11-04 17:00:00.000
```

For times between 00:00:00-01:00:00 it will get the range 23:00:00-00:00:00 from the previous day.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @today datetime
set @today=GETDATE()
select @today, DATEADD(HOUR, -2, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, @today), 0)), DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, -1, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, @today), 0)))
```

result:

```
2013-11-04 17:42:17.933 2013-11-04 15:00:00.000 2013-11-04 15:59:00.000
```

Comment: This actually returns the wrong hour. If it is 11:50 this will return 9:00 and 9:59, not 10:00 and 10:59 as the OP requested. Also, as I noted in my answer, the "end" of the hour isn't really 10:59.